# I'm a beginner in Java and got stuck here... When I tried to call block a error occurred

Tags: java

Class example

```
public static void main (String        ARGS[]){
         Block: {
                         System.out.println("hi");
                      }
     Block;
           }
```

Could anyone help me.. to tell me the reason n concept Why m getting error and is it solvable?Or m going in wrong direction..

Comment: Why downward ... Could anyone sort out n explain me n help me to understand the concept  instead of downwarding . M a novice in Java .

Comment: It is not solvable. And yes, you are going in wrong direction.

Comment: @Thomas But with break and continue we reach to that block

Comment: No, with `break block;` and `continue block;` you can jump **out** of that block. The label is not meant as a point to jump **in** from outside.

Comment: I recommend you forget about labels in Java, because they are very rarely used. I never needed labels in my Java code and never saw labels in other people's Java code.

Comment: Okk. I switch than

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't. Labeling a block of code is not a valid syntax in java. In some programming languages like C, it is valid. You can use the `goto` keyword to shift the execution to that block of code identified by that label. But in Java, no. You can't. Any for your other question of 'why it is not allowed', you can search SO for old answers.

Comment: Downvoter, what's wrong with this answer? Do you think the answer is 'yes, it is allowed'?

Comment: Blocks are used with break and continue .. so can we call question is this

Comment: @ShubhamMaheshwari, `break` and `continue` are keywords meant specifically for loops.

Answer (score 0):

That would require the usage of the `goto` keyword, which is not available in Java because it may lead to *Spaghetti Code*. A well structured program shouldn't need such blocks. For more on why the `goto` is bad, read:

http://www.drdobbs.com/jvm/programming-with-reason-why-is-goto-bad/228200966

Comment: Downvoting should require an explanation.

Comment: I would never down-vote someone for giving me an answer/opinion unless it was wrong.

Comment: That's y m asking if we can't use go to can we call

Answer (score -1):

Block methods are called automatically when we load the class in JVM, first the blocks are executed then main Method will execute.
Like

```
public class ConstructorBlockExample{

    {
        System.out.println("This is first constructor block");
    }

    public ConstructorBlockExample(){
        System.out.println("This is no parameter constructor");
    }

    public ConstructorBlockExample(String param1){
        System.out.println("This is single parameter constructor");
    }

    public ConstructorBlockExample(String param1, String param2){
        System.out.println("This is two parameters constructor");
    }

    {
        System.out.println("This is second constructor block");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        ConstructorBlockExample constrBlockEx = 
                     new ConstructorBlockExample();
        ConstructorBlockExample constrBlockEx1 = 
                     new ConstructorBlockExample("param1");
        ConstructorBlockExample constrBlockEx2 = 
                     new ConstructorBlockExample("param1", "param2");
    }
}
```

and Output is

```
This is first constructor block 
This is second constructor block
This is no parameter constructor
This is first constructor block
This is second constructor block
This is single parameter constructor
This is first constructor block
This is second constructor block
This is two parameters constructor
```

And You can use label for a block, but it mostly used to break or continue the loop inside block like:

```
 outer:
 for(int i=...){
   for(int j=..){
     ...
     break outer; // leaves both loops   

   } 

 }
```

Comment: In main method I asked not from class

Comment: i just gave you the complete java program to see how the block are working, it's also a main class and it contains main() method and you can see the output of this class and then imagine output of your code

Comment: U are not understanding my question

Comment: yes, you mean can we use label for blocks, if we use label then how we can call the blocks? it's JVM who call the blocks automatically, you can't call blocks .

Answer (score -1):

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html

A block is executed by executing each of the local variable declaration statements and other statements in order from first to last (left to right). If all of these block statements complete normally, then the block completes normally. If any of these block statements complete abruptly for any reason, then the block completes abruptly for the same reason.

[image]

Comment: Question is of can we call like function

Answer (score -3):

Java 7 allows String as the switch.
An Enum workaround using MyEnum.valueOf(str) can be made to work.
A switch on the String (or Object)'s hashcode plus some more if-then-else if is possible but would only make sense for lots of possibilities, in which case the whole thing is probably due for an overhaul.

Comment: My question is can we call

Comment: in that case, yes, according to the manual: A block is a sequence of statements, local class declarations, and local variable declaration statements within braces.


Block:
    { BlockStatementsopt }

BlockStatements:
    BlockStatement
    BlockStatements BlockStatement

BlockStatement:
    LocalVariableDeclarationStatement
    ClassDeclaration
    Statement